# Bulk Deletion in B+ Trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

Deleting single elements from a B+ tree is fine.
However i wanted to know if there is some way to delete a large no of elements in the tree in at least less than O(nlogn) time.

Is it possible to delete bulk elements of the tree in the same time if they happen to be consecutive in the linked list?

Comment: On a side note, if deleting a single element from the tree takes `O(nlogn)` time, then deleting, say, 100 element would take `O(100 * nlogn)` which is still `O(nlogn)` ;)

Comment: Deleting a single element would take O(logn) time only.... However the no of elements to be deleted can vary from 1 to n.

Comment: so if it was `n` deletions it wouldn't be `O(nlogn)` anymore, nice catch!

Comment: It would be O(log(factorial(n))) in the worst case which would then be O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.  In some cases, yes.

Very specifically you can build a B+ tree of size `n` from a *sorted* data set in time `O(n)`.  Furthermore with a large data set you can sort on disk using streaming operations much faster then you can do lots of random seeks.

The result is the old database advice for large bulk loads.  "Drop indexes, load data, rebuild indexes."  Or in your case if the to-delete data came sorted you could build a sorted list of the data that we want, then build a new B+ tree out of it.

A variant of this is to have a B+ tree that records when old data was deleted for some time.  Then you can do a bulk delete just by walking through the tree and marking things deleted very rapidly.  And only occasionally compress the tree by walking the whole thing and rewriting it all.

But in general I'd recommend manipulating the data structure one element at a time.  Because, as I like to joke, *log(n) is a constant.  For Google it is a slightly larger constant.*